# scrollTop & scrollLeft do not work on display:none elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to scroll an hidden element before I show it. This is the code i'm working with:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```css
.main { 
    display:none; 
    position:abolsute; 
    width:250px;height:250px; 
    overflow:scroll;
}
.bg { 
    background: blue url(http://defaulttester.com/img/bg-landing-mario.jpg); 
    width:1200px; 
    height:800px; 
}
```

---

```js
$(".main").scrollTop($(".bg").height()/2);
$(".main").scrollLeft($(".bg").width()/2);
```

IT works fine if its showing but if its `display:hidden` it will simple not work. Is there anyway to avoid this and make it work?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpjzJ/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `visibility: hidden;` or some class like this instead:

```css
.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}
```

Or this (from Boilerplate):

```css
.visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```

Something with `display: none;` has no location on the page, as you probably knew.

[Check out this article on the subject.](http://alistapart.com/article/now-you-see-me)

Comment: There must be a better way of doing this? There are hacks. I can't use .show() on an a visibility: hidden; element?

Comment: Yeah, you should use toggleClass(), or addClass() / removeClass() with one of the classes I show here. Or $('stuff').css('visibility', 'visible');

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to just set scrollLeft and scrollTop to 0(since that was my goal), one very hacky solution is to follow these steps:

- Get a reference to the element you want to reset.
- Get a reference to the element's parent.
- Remove the element from the parent.
- Append the element back to the parent.

scrollTop and scrollLeft will now be set back to 0 even though they are invisible.

Answer (score 2):

```
function resetScroll(element) {
    element.parentElement.replaceChild(element,element)
}
```

This will set both scrollTop and scrollLeft to 0 even if display none.

Example use:

```
resetScroll(document.getElementById("my_scroll"))
```

Comment: caution: This doesn't work on Edge v42(maybe IE also), replaceChild with same element removes the element

Comment: I haven't confirmed that this works in Edge (if that's still a thing) but, in JQuery, I detach the object and then append it back to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but the way I solved this is to add a one-time `IntersectionObserver` that triggers the first time the element becomes visible. Here's a function to add a callback for when an element first becomes visible:

```js
function onVisible(element, callback) {
  new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if(entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        callback(element);
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }).observe(element);
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
let myElement = document.querySelector("#myElement");
// When the element first becomes visible, scroll it to 500px:
onVisible(myElement, el=>el.scrollTop=500);
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/gigumewemo/edit?html,output